# on hover change other classes that are before

Tags: css

This work good ..

```
#a:hover + #b {
background: #ccc
}

<div id="a">Div A</div>
<div id="b">Div B</div>
```

but the opposite does not work. It's a solution for that ??

```
#b:hover + #a {
background: #ccc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select previous siblings using CSS. You could alternatively use jQuery solution to do that!

Comment: thanks, I'll try with jquery